# Losing carriage returns in variable assignment

Tags: bash, shell

If I assign a variable in Bash like so:

```
PRIVATE_KEY="$(< ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"
```

and then immediately dump that to a file:

```
echo $PRIVATE_KEY > tmp.txt
```

and then compare this to the original:

```
diff ~/.ssh/id_rsa tmp.txt
```

I do not get a match as all of the carriage returns (or maybe it's line feeds) have been stripped off in the original variable assignment. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes when you echo the variable to the file:

```
echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > tmp.txt
```

That will preserve line breaks and spacing.

Comment: So simple but so perfectly right. Thanks. :)